# How to use pyfakefs in conjunction with importlib.resources.path

Tags: python, pytest, python-3.7, python-importlib, pyfakefs

Given some installed package, the following code can be used to print its location on the filesystem:

```py
import importlib.resources

def print_package_path(pkg):
    with importlib.resources.path(pkg, "") as path:
        print(path)

print_package_path("importlib")
# /home/me/python_3.8/lib/python3.8/importlib on my machine
```

If I want to test a function that contains such a statement with `pytest` as the test suite and `pyfakefs` to fake the filesystem during the test, it will crash with a confusing error (`IsADirectoryError: [Errno 21] Is a directory` on ubuntu and `PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied` on windows) - it's not even necessary to do anything with the `fs` fixture, it just needs to be part of the test function's signature, e.g.

```py
def test_package_path(fs):
    print_package_path("importlib")
```

will result in

```
______________________________ test_package_path _______________________________

fs = <pyfakefs.fake_filesystem.FakeFilesystem object at 0x7f84f2996910>

    def test_package_path(fs):
>       print_package_path()

/home/me/foo.py:11: 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
/home/me/foo.py:4: in print_package_path
    with importlib.resources.path("importlib", "") as path:
/home/me/pythons/python_3.8/lib/python3.8/contextlib.py:113: in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
/home/me/venv/lib/python3.8/importlib/resources.py:201: in path
    with open_binary(package, resource) as fp:
/home/me/venv/lib/python3.8/importlib/resources.py:91: in open_binary
    return reader.open_resource(resource)
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 

self = <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7f84f7527370>
resource = ''

>   ???
E   IsADirectoryError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: '/home/me/venv/lib/python3.8/importlib'

<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>:988: IsADirectoryError
```

which makes zero sense to me. Should a directory never have been usable as a resource in the first place?

I must admit I don't really understand the `importlib.resources` module, so I might just be using it wrong (my actual use case is creating a file during development, and avoiding the use of `__file__` to find the right location).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [pyfakefs documentation](http://jmcgeheeiv.github.io/pyfakefs/release/usage.html#modules-not-working-with-pyfakefs) that states:

> Modules may not work with pyfakefs for several reasons. pyfakefs works by patching some file system related modules and functions, specifically:
>
> - most file system related functions in the os and os.path modules
> - the pathlib module
> - the build-in open function and io.open
> - shutil.disk_usage

Simply including `fs` fixture enables patching these modules. If you really need to use `pyfakefs`, either provide everything your code expects (even indirectly) or start your tests with paused `fs` and enable it only to test specific things that can't be tested otherwise. In this case it's `io.open` that breaks.

---

Providing the expected files works by calling [`fs.add_real_directory`](http://jmcgeheeiv.github.io/pyfakefs/release/usage.html#access-to-files-in-the-real-file-system) before executing the functions that rely on the existence of the files, like this:

```py
def test_package_path(fs):
    fs.add_real_directory(os.path.dirname(importlib.__file__))
    print_package_path()
```

, where `importlib.__file__` needs to be replaced with the full path of whatever is accessed by `importlib.resources.path` in the tested code. This method is also safe against file creation in the tested function, since the fake fs is aware of all changes and never applies them to the actual files:

> The access to the files is by default read-only, but even if you add them using read_only=False, the files are written only in the fake system (e.g. in memory). The real files are never changed.

Comment: Thanks for finding the docu. Do you have an idea which change would be required to get the example code to work while still working in some kind of fake filesystem?

Comment: Importlib works on current VM runtime so I suppose it will not be easy. I would rather skip testing built-in modules and mock result of importlib.resources.path() call instead.

Comment: that's a the best way to go about it, probably. It's a bit annoying if the result is used for a bunch of other operations which then all need to be mocked, which is the case for what I'm trying to do, but if there is no way around it I might as well just start.

Comment: That being said, I [did file a bug](https://github.com/jmcgeheeiv/pyfakefs/issues/505) with the project itself, and it seems that what I want can also be achieved by mapping the relevant part of the filesystem that I want to talk to into the fake fs. I extended your answer with the method that one of the maintainers pointed out in there.